# How to install Netgear/MT7612U driver in Manjaro Linux?

Tags: networking, wifi, usb

I would like to set up an AP for my Linux PC as per [these instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/software_access_point) but this device won't show up in `iw addr` command

```
$ iw addr
nl80211 not found.

$ iw list
nl80211 not found.

$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:9c:dc:a4:9d:0e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

But it is listed in the connected USB section:

```
$lsusb
...
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
...
```

After downloading the tar file from [MediaTek](https://www.mediatek.com/products/broadbandWifi/mt7612u) and extracting its contents. I tried to run `make` to build the binaries. The folowwing error was then thrown.

```
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ebe/Downloads/DPO/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ebe/Downloads/DPO/tools'
/home/ebe/Downloads/DPO/tools/bin2h
chipset = mt7662u
chipset = mt7632u
chipset = mt7612u
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/ebe/Downloads/DPO/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/4.16.7-rt1-MANJARO/build SUBDIRS=/home/ebe/Downloads/DPO/os/linux modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.16.7-rt1-MANJARO/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:391: LINUX] Error 2
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Is there any other way to install this driver for Arch/Manjaro?

Comment: Your `lsusb` output shows the device as a MT7601U, but you're installing drivers for the MT7612U ?

Comment: @Lawrence I thought that might make it get detected in the `iw addr` list. Am I doing something wrong. Is there an alternative for this?

Comment: Installing drivers for a different device probably isn't going to help. What's the output of `iw list` and `ip link` ?

Comment: @Lawrence I've added the output of `iw list` and `ip link` to the post.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Thanks for the info. I just was about to troubleshoot the installation dependencies; you saved my time. Could you please provide an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compile the wrong model of driver of your wifi.

Nevertheless for Manjaro you do not need to compile anything.

For your chipset, install the `mt7601u-dkms` package. it does provide a more stable kernel module than the source code the manufacturer provides.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried building with `yaourt -S mt7601u-dkms` but the build fails with `ERROR: Failure while downloading http://www.mediatek.com/AmazonS3/Downloads/linux/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913.tar.bz2
    Aborting...`. I never edited an AUR build before; is there anything I should do to change this link?

Comment: I managed to replace the broken link with `https://d86o2zu8ugzlg.cloudfront.net/mediatek-craft/drivers/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913.tar.bz2` in the PKGBUILD and the build was successful. However, while installing this error came up: `error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
mt7601u-dkms: /usr/lib/firmware/mt7601u.bin exists in filesystem`

Comment: Sorry. Just had to restart the computer with the usb connected and the adapter works.

Comment: Good news, congrats.